# T-SQL Case logic

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I cant seem to figure out the code that I would need to write to achieve the following. If a GETDATE() is Monday than I want to delete all the data that is a year old + 2 more days (job wont run on Sat. and Sun.). I am trying to get the following code to work without writing it twice..i.e achieve the same effect in shorter piece of code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
DELETE FROM dbo.table
WHERE AddedOn = CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,'01/23/2012') = 'Monday' then   CONVERT(date,dateadd("d",-368,getdate())) else 
CONVERT(date,dateadd("d",-365,getdate())) end

DELETE FROM dbo.table
WHERE AddedOn = CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,'01/23/2012') = 'Monday' then CONVERT(date,dateadd("d",-367,getdate())) else 
CONVERT(date,dateadd("d",-365,getdate())) end
```

Comment: Have you considered leap years?

Comment: not really. But if it were to delete anything that is 368 days old, it wouldnt really matter if it were a leap year or not. Hence 368 should take care of even the leap years.

Comment: Have you considered using an inequality instead?  IF you are running this every day(ish), do you want to delete all data older than a year old?  If so just use an inequality and you are set for all cases

Comment: Is there any reason that you are using CONVERT to delete specific days?  Why not use a format like `where addedon < dateadd("d",-365,getdate())` ? 
If this is permissible, then the case statement needs to be in place of the 365 only.

Comment: I was simply too lazy to think about it. The convert is a paste from other piece of code. Since this project was really small, I didnt take the trouble of thinking a whole lot. But I will keep your point in mind for future use. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont really understand why you are doing an between statement if you want to delete all records older then a year. Isn't it just :

```
DELETE FROM dbo.table where AddenOn < DATEADD(year, '01/23/2012', -1)
```

So if you run this script only on weekdays, on monday it will remove a couple more days.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, if I understand your question properly:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.table
    WHERE AddedOn BETWEEN
    CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,'01/23/2012') = 'Monday' 
         then   CONVERT(date,dateadd("d",-368,getdate())) 
         else   CONVERT(date,dateadd("d",-365,getdate())) 
     end
    AND
    CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,'01/23/2012') = 'Monday' 
        then CONVERT(date,dateadd("d",-367,getdate())) 
    else CONVERT(date,dateadd("d",-365,getdate())) 
         end
```

Comment: Thats the one I was looking for. Thanks Sparky.